# Azure Notification Hub not sending notifications randomly

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

For a few weeks there is an issue with Azure Notification Hub - we have a backend service that registers devices & schedules notifications. When one of the notifications is triggered, then we send it to Azure based on the device type (create the payload and all of that).

The response we get from azure is positive, the notification has been enqueued and is ready to be sent. However, it seems that Azure does not send them all. No error is thrown but only a small percentage is sent. It also does not seem to depend on the device type.

[image]

There are no logs to read - or none tha I can find and I cannot pin point the issue.
We have an endpoint that triggers the sending of a notification - we did a test run with 30 notifications (similar and different payloads for the same device) and it all went well.

Not sure how to troubleshoot this or what might cause this. I understood from the documentation that the device might be inactive and then the notification is deleted from the queue after a while. But it seems that the said device receives 1 out of 3 notifications (sent at the same time).

Any feedback would be appreciated.

**Edit update:**

After upgrading to the Standard plan, we managed to get some more information and it looks like Azure gives back a "Success" with a count of "1" but the device does not receive the notification - the problem is, this happens randomly. It's not always the same device that does or does not receive the notification.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this isn't a super helpful answer, but could you please open a support ticket in the Azure Portal for us to investigate your particular case? This does not seem like expected behavior so the team will have to look into the logs for your namespace and hub.

One immediate thought - there is de-duplication logic when sending notifications. So within a period of time (something like 15 minutes) if the same notification payload is being sent to the same device, Notification Hubs will automatically drop that duplicate notification.

Comment: Yeah, I opened a ticket a few hours ago. Thing is, we have an endpoint to force push (send a notification now)  - we ran that 50 times with the same notification (payload) for the same device and all 50 were received.. Thats where it gets confusing,

Comment: An endpoint in Notification Hubs for force push? Could you clarify? If it's the debug send endpoint, that one actually intentionally _skips_ the deduplication logic because it assumes you don't want to dedupe when testing.

Comment: an endpoint on my API that pushed the notification to azure "now" compared to "scheduled".